# How to select based on value of another select (hierarchy)

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a table called `bom` that looks like this:

| id | skuFather | skuSon | qtys |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A00001 | 00001 | 1 |
| 2 | A00001 | 00002 | 1 |
| 3 | A00001 | 00003 | 1 |
| 4 | A00001 | 00004 | 1 |
| 5 | A00001 | 00005 | 12 |
| 6 | A00001 | 00006 | 3 |
| 7 | A00001 | 00007 | 4 |
| 8 | A00001 | 00008 | 1 |
| 9 | A00001 | 00009 | 2 |
| 10 | A00001 | 00010 | 1 |
| 11 | A00001 | 00011 | 1 |
| 12 | A00001 | 00012 | 1 |
| 13 | A00001 | 00013 | 1 |
| 14 | 00004 | 00015 | 2 |
| 15 | 00004 | 00016 | 1 |
| 16 | 00004 | 00017 | 1 |
| 17 | 00004 | 00018 | 2 |
| 18 | 00004 | 00019 | 1 |
| 19 | 00004 | 00020 | 3 |
| 20 | 00004 | 00021 | 1 |
| 21 | 00019 | 00031 | 1 |
| 22 | 00019 | 00032 | 1 |
| 23 | 00019 | 00033 | 1 |

I need to perform a select that returns a list where the `skuFather` lists all the `skuFather` and `skuSon` are inside the main `skuFather`.

Using **"A00001"** here as an example, I need it to return the same as the table below:

| BOM | qtys |
| --- | --- |
| 00001 | 1 |
| 00002 | 1 |
| 00003 | 1 |
| 00004 | 1 |
| 00015 | 2 |
| 00016 | 1 |
| 00017 | 1 |
| 00018 | 2 |
| 00019 | 1 |
| 00031 | 1 |
| 00032 | 1 |
| 00033 | 1 |
| 00020 | 3 |
| 00021 | 1 |
| 00005 | 12 |
| 00006 | 3 |
| 00007 | 4 |
| 00008 | 1 |
| 00009 | 2 |
| 00010 | 1 |
| 00011 | 1 |
| 00012 | 1 |
| 00013 | 1 |

I tried the following query:

```sql
select skuFather, skuSon, qtys 
from bom 
where skuFather in (
    select skuSon
    from bom 
    where skuFather = 'A00001'
)
```

It did not produce the expected result.

Comment: Can you replace `in` with `=` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH RECURSIVE sku_hierarchy AS (
  SELECT skuFather, skuSon, qtys
  FROM bom
  WHERE skuFather = 'A00001'  -- Replace 'A00001' with the desired skuFather value
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT bom.skuFather, bom.skuSon, bom.qtys
  FROM bom
  INNER JOIN sku_hierarchy ON sku_hierarchy.skuSon = bom.skuFather
)
SELECT skuSon AS "BOM", qtys
FROM sku_hierarchy
ORDER BY skuSon;
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but show *SQL error code 104*
*CTE sku_hierarchy  has cyclic dependencies*

Comment: Is it possible to create the same query without using the "WITH RECURSIVE" command?